# Couldn't Resize JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I Have added `JTree` and a `JInternalFrame` to `JDesktopPane`.
I want to resize the `JInternalFrame` but couldn't do it.But I can move the Internalframe inside it.

```
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.OverlayLayout;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;

public class TableDiff {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JDesktopPane panel = new JDesktopPane() {
       // @Override
       // public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled() {
       //     return false;
       // }
    };
    panel.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(panel));
    JTree tree = new JTree();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(i + "x");
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(i + "x"));
        }
        root.add(node);
    }
    tree.setModel(new DefaultTreeModel(root));
    JScrollPane tscrollpane = new JScrollPane(tree);

    JInternalFrame iFrame = new JInternalFrame("asd");
    iFrame.setClosable(true);
    iFrame.setMaximizable(true);
    iFrame.setResizable(true);
    iFrame.setIconifiable(true);
    iFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
   // tscrollpane.setAlignmentX(1.0f);
  //  tscrollpane.setAlignmentY(0.0f);
   // iFrame.setAlignmentX(0.0f);
   // iFrame.setAlignmentY(0.0f);
    panel.add(tscrollpane);
    panel.add(iFrame);

    iFrame.setVisible(true);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the use of an `OverlayLayout`.

Simply remove the following line:

```
panel.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(panel));
```

---

Also, very importantly, do not forget to set the preferred size of your `JFrame` and `JInternalFrame`!

As per the [Oracle documentation for using Internal Frames with Java Swing (link)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html):

> **You must set the size of the internal frame.**
>   If you do not set the
>   size of the internal frame, it will have zero size and thus never be
>   visible. You can set the size using one of the following methods:
>   `setSize`, `pack`, or `setBounds`.

Comment: If I remove it, it is simply showing white panel with no contents.Have you checked the code by removing it?

Comment: As featured in my answer, you **do** need to set a size to your `JInternalFrame` :)